# Resizing dynamic disk

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

I merged 2 partitions using other software, instead of using Windows' tool (<kbd>Administrative Tools</kbd>-><kbd>Computer Management</kbd>-><kbd>Disk Management</kbd>). Is there any way to un-merge those 2 partitions, or at least somehow turn a hard drive from a dynamic disk type to a basic disk type, so I could 'cut' some space and make new partition without formatting whole drive?

Comment: [Easus Partition Master](http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm) will do this and is free for home use.

Answer (score 0):

There is tool, called EASEUS Partition Master, which can resize dynamical disks, and make them  non dynamical. However home edition wont let you do this, because it doesnt support batch operations, so you'll have either to make bootable cd or flash drive